# Figuring out the AC equivalent circuit(re model) of a Pre-Amplifier and Tone Control Circuit

Tags: ac, bjt, npn, preamp

I need help figuring out the AC equivalent circuit of this preamplifier circuit. I'm quite familiar with all the simple BJT configurations but this is my first configuring such a relatively complicated circuit. How do I start? All I know is that all the capacitors would act as short circuits and the transistors would transform to its equivalent components.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f1n5Io.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Answer (score 1):

> All I know is that all the capacitors would act as short circuits

Um ... no.  A critical aspect of this circuit is that the impedance of the capacitors is ((not)) constant; it varies as a function of the frequency of the signal going through it.  This is why (in round numbers) a treble control does not affect the bass frequencies.  Write down the equation for the impedance of a capacitor at a specific frequency; you will use it a lot for this circuit.

BTW - The tone control part of this circuit is called a Baxandall tone control, named after its inventor, Peter Baxandall.  An important requirement for it is that the signal source has a very low output impedance.  In your circuit, the source comes to the circuit through a pot, so the source impedance the circuit sees varies from 0 to 25 K ohms, depending on the volume control setting.  It is a minor point, but it removes one of the assumptions you can make when analyzing the overall circuit.

Comment: In other words: Baxandall tone control won't work very well when fed from a pot with value similar to the tone adjust potentiometer. A buffer stage is needed on the input. It will "work" as shown, but the adjustment range won't be as good as it otherwise would be.

Answer (score 0):

In this circuit, with numerous AC feedback paths (even the top-right C13 is a feedback element, with the external load affecting the output voltage and thus how much signal comes back thru the VDD node), the only AC model is this actual circuit.

Given the top left capacitor, 100uF tied thru R13 to the VDD node, has no purpose, I doubt this is the real circuit.